# Arangodb dynamic index on object keys

Tags: indexing, arangodb, aql

Arangodb 2.8b3

Have document with some property "specification", can have 1-100 keys inside, like

```
document {
  ...
  specification: {
      key1: "value",
      ...
      key10: "value"
  }
}
```

Task fast query by specification.key

```
For Doc IN MyCollection FILTER Doc.specification['key1'] == "value" RETURN Doc
```

Tried create hash indexes with field: "specification", "specification.*", specification[*], specification[*].*

Index never used, any solution without reorganizing structure or plans for future exists?

Answer (score 2):

No, we currently don't have any smart idea how to handle indices for structures like that. The memory usage would also increase since the attribute names would also have to be present in the index for each indexed value.

What we will release [with 2.8 is the ability to use indices on array structures](https://docs.arangodb.com/2.8/IndexHandling/IndexBasics.html#indexing-array-values):

```
db.posts.ensureIndex({ type: "hash", fields: [ "tags[*]" ] });
```

with documents like:

```
{ tags: [ "foobar", "bar", "anotherTag" ] }
```

Using AQL queries like this:

```
FOR doc IN posts
  FILTER 'foobar' IN doc.tags[*]
  RETURN doc
```

You could also index documents under arrays:

```
db.posts.ensureIndex({ type: "hash", fields: [ "tags[*].value" ] });
db.posts.insert({
  tags: [ { key: "key1", value: "foobar"},
          { key: "key2", value: "baz" },
          { key: "key3", value: "quux" }
        ] });
```

The following query will then use the array index:

```
FOR doc IN posts
  FILTER 'foobar' IN doc.tags[*].value
  RETURN doc
```

However, the asterisk can only be used for array accesses - it can't substitute key matches in objects.

Comment: Last variant not solve, I search not value, I need compare value with key ( key = A and value = B) not value in values. 
Elasticsearch have dynamic mapping index for objects, now I use it for lookup, and then select records from arangodb by ids. As strange as it may sound, but it is faster ..